# Html5 var in JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I am currently trying to save a text var from HTML5 (with canvas) into jsp but cant find out how to do it or if is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "how to get a JSP var into an HTML 5 compoent"

```
yourHTML5var = <%=jspvar%>
```

Otherwise you would need a webservice to submit client side variables to a server for server side use. Be sure to sanitize whatever you send from the client to the server as well. Good luck!

edit: per comments - HTML 5 has some native API use : http://today.java.net/article/2010/03/31/html5-server-push-technologies-part-1  -- ultimately though you will need a serverside component to process these requests

Comment: yes i was actually looking for a way to get the client edited variable into a database by jsp

Comment: you would essentially need to engineer a servlet to handle these requests. You can of course handle client side processing via AJAX standards or what have you - but ultimately you would still need a server side processing component. HTML 5 has some native features, take a look @ http://today.java.net/article/2010/03/31/html5-server-push-technologies-part-1 ( adding this to original answer )